# Decoding 3-byte integer in Perl

Tags: perl, unpack

I'm reading a binary file format that starts out with 4 constant check bytes, followed by 3 octets that indicate how long the data portion of the record will be.  I can decode this as follows:

```
read($fh, $x, 7) or do {
  last if eof;
  die "Can't read: $!";
};
my ($type, $l1, $l2, $l3) = unpack("a4 C3", $x);
my $length = $l1 << 16 | $l2 << 8 | $l3;
```

Is there a more direct way to read that 3-byte value, without intermediate variables?  Something I'm missing in the `pack` specifications maybe?  I haven't used `pack` very much except for hex encoding and other dilettantish pursuits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `unpack` doesn't support 3-byte (or arbitrary length) integers, but you could use an unsigned 16-bit big-endian int to save a little work:

```
my ($type, $l1, $l23) = unpack("a4 Cn", $x);
my $length = $l1 << 16 | $l23;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could insert a null byte into the string in order to be able to use the "N" format:

```
substr($x, 4, 0, "\0");
my ($type, $length) = unpack "a4 N", $x;
```

Edit: Or else unpack in two steps:

```
my ($type, $length) = unpack "a4 a3", $x;
$length = unpack "N", "\0" . $length;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my $type = unpack("a4", $x);
my $len  = unpack("N", "\0".substr($x, 4));
```

or

```
my ($type, $plen) = unpack("a4 a3", $x);
my $len = unpack("N", "\0$plen");
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Your method for getting the type is fine. However, I suggest that you unpack the length separately as a four-byte integer, then discard the first byte of those four bytes. This is more efficient even though it overlaps and discards the last byte of the type.

```
my $type = unpack("a4", $x);
my $length = unpack("x3N", $x); # skips the first 3 bytes of your original 7-byte string
$length = $length & 0xFFFFFF; # returns only the last 3 bytes of the four-byte integer
```

Comment: Cool.  I'll keep that in my back pocket if I need better performance - might confuse the next person (who might be my future self) though.