# perl - parse signed integer for byte lengths of 3,5,6,7

Tags: perl

I have a business requirement to read signed integer values with byte lengths varying from 1 to 8.

The standard implementation of int values occupies bytes of the order of 2**n

```
> perl -e ' $x=chr(253); $y=unpack "c",$x; printf("%d\n",$y) ' # 1 byte
-3
> perl -e ' $x=chr(255).chr(253); $y=unpack "s>",$x; printf("%d\n",$y)' # 2 byte
-3
> perl -e ' $x=chr(255) x 3;$x.=chr(253); $y=unpack "i>",$x; printf("%d\n",$y) ' # 4 byte
-3
> perl -e ' $x=chr(255) x 7;$x.=chr(253); $y=unpack "q>",$x; printf("%d\n",$y) ' # 8 byte
-3
>
```

For 3, 5, 6, 7 bytes, I'm trying like below

```
> perl -e ' $x=chr(255) x 2;$x.=chr(253); $y=unpack "i>",$x; printf("%d\n",$y) '
0
>
```

But it is wrong, I need -3.

This link [Decoding 3-byte integer in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512295/decoding-3-byte-integer-in-perl) answers for unsigned numbers but doesn't solve my problem.

Can someone help to get signed values for 3, 5, 6, 7 bytes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To extend the size of a 2's-complement integer, one must use [sign extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension). This means you need to copy sign bit of the number into every bit you add.

```
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------+
  |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |      |
  v   v   v   v   v   v   v   v      |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |  |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | ...
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--
MSB         new byte          LSB  MSB        old byte(s)        LSB
```

So `0000 0011` (3) becomes `0000 0000 0000 0011` (3)
And `1111 1101` (-3) becomes `1111 1111 1111 1101` (-3).

General solutions:

- To unpack a 1- to 8-byte, big-endian number:

  ```
  unpack( "q>", substr( ( ord($_) & 0x80 ? "\xFF"x7 : "\x00"x7 ) . $_, -8 ) )
  ```

  Test:

  ```
  $ perl -e'
     for ( map { ( "\x00" x $_ ) . "\x03", ( "\xFF" x $_ ) . "\xFD" } 0..7 ) {
        printf "%v02X => %d\n",
           $_, unpack( "q>", substr( ( ord($_) & 0x80 ? "\xFF"x7 : "\x00"x7 ) . $_, -8 ) );
     }
  '
  03 => 3
  FD => -3
  00.03 => 3
  FF.FD => -3
  00.00.03 => 3
  FF.FF.FD => -3
  00.00.00.03 => 3
  FF.FF.FF.FD => -3
  00.00.00.00.03 => 3
  FF.FF.FF.FF.FD => -3
  00.00.00.00.00.03 => 3
  FF.FF.FF.FF.FF.FD => -3
  00.00.00.00.00.00.03 => 3
  FF.FF.FF.FF.FF.FF.FD => -3
  00.00.00.00.00.00.00.03 => 3
  FF.FF.FF.FF.FF.FF.FF.FD => -3
  ```
- To unpack a 1- to 8-byte, little-endian number:

  ```
  unpack( "q<", $_ . ( ord(substr($_, -1)) & 0x80 ? "\xFF"x7 : "\x00"x7 ) )
  ```

  Test:

  ```
  $ perl -e'
     for ( map { "\x03" . ( "\x00" x $_ ), "\xFD" . ( "\xFF" x $_ ) } 0..7 ) {
        printf "%v02X => %d\n",
           $_, unpack( "q<", $_ . ( ord(substr($_, -1)) & 0x80 ? "\xFF"x7 : "\x00"x7 ) );
     }
  '
  03 => 3
  FD => -3
  03.00 => 3
  FD.FF => -3
  03.00.00 => 3
  FD.FF.FF => -3
  03.00.00.00 => 3
  FD.FF.FF.FF => -3
  03.00.00.00.00 => 3
  FD.FF.FF.FF.FF => -3
  03.00.00.00.00.00 => 3
  FD.FF.FF.FF.FF.FF => -3
  03.00.00.00.00.00.00 => 3
  FD.FF.FF.FF.FF.FF.FF => -3
  03.00.00.00.00.00.00.00 => 3
  FD.FF.FF.FF.FF.FF.FF.FF => -3
  ```

Specific solutions:

- To unpack a 3-byte, big-endian number:

  ```
  unpack( "l>", ( ord($_) & 0x80 ? "\xFF" : "\x00" ) . $_ )
  ```
- To unpack a 3-byte, little-endian number:

  ```
  unpack( "l<", $_ . ( ord(substr($_, -1)) & 0x80 ? "\xFF" : "\x00" ) )
  ```
- To unpack a 5-byte big-endian number:

  ```
  unpack( "q>", ( ord($_) & 0x80 ? "\xFF"x3 : "\x00"x3 ) . $_ )
  ```
- To unpack a 5-byte little-endian number:

  ```
  unpack( "q<", $_ . ( ord(substr($_, -1)) & 0x80 ? "\xFF"x3 : "\x00"x3 ) )
  ```
- To unpack a 6-byte big-endian number:

  ```
  unpack( "q>", ( ord($_) & 0x80 ? "\xFF"x2 : "\x00"x2 ) . $_ )
  ```
- To unpack a 6-byte little-endian number:

  ```
  unpack( "q<", $_ . ( ord(substr($_, -1)) & 0x80 ? "\xFF"x2 : "\x00"x2 ) )
  ```
- To unpack a 7-byte, big-endian number:

  ```
  unpack( "q>", ( ord($_) & 0x80 ? "\xFF" : "\x00" ) . $_ )
  ```
- To unpack a 7-byte, little-endian number:

  ```
  unpack( "q<", $_ . ( ord(substr($_, -1)) & 0x80 ? "\xFF" : "\x00" ) )
  ```

Comment: can you check once.. im not getting -3 for my examples

Comment: Argh, I got the condition backwards throughout. Fixed.